# Craft CMS usage of punycode

Tags: craft3

Our malware scanner detected punycode as malware in `/vendor/bower-asset/punycode/...`

In light of punycode being used to mask some IDNs like wikipedia.org etc. I would like to know what the usage of punycode is in Craft installations.

I saw that punycode is listed under the `devDependencies` in `/vendor/craftcms/cms/package.json` however it was not installed on all of our Craft installations.

The file that's being marked as malware is:

`/vendor/bower-asset/punycode/tests/data.js`

Answer (score 2):

I can't say officially (since I had nothing to do with building it), but it looks like the [Punycode library](https://github.com/true/php-punycode) specifically does this:

> This library converts a Unicode encoded domain name to a IDNA ASCII form and vice-versa.

I'm not sure why it's getting flagged as malware, it seems like a pretty harmless little library. If you're still concerned about it, I'd either reach out to Pixel & Tonic directly (support@craftcms.com) or post an [issue](https://github.com/true/php-punycode/issues) on the Punycode repo.